# #NAME! error while setting user defined 'SpellNumber' function to excel cell by apache POI

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula, apache-poi

I am overwriting an already existing excel sheet, where I have to set `SpellNumber` function which is user defined by apache POI.

But when I set the formula `SpellNumber` to excel cell by apache POI, it is showing `=@@SpellNumber` in excel cell instead of `=@SpellNumber`.

Do any one have any idea why POI is appending the extra **@** symbol to cell

Comment: How are you setting the formula? It will be easier to identify what is going wrong if you post the relevant code. (Not the whole program! Just the section where you set or evaluate the formula)

Comment: setting the cell formula like this  ....... 
cell54.setCellFormula("SpellNumber(L13,BB13)");

Comment: Gagravarr can you please help me on how to set a user defined function to excel cell using apache POI